# Python Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python

```
from decimal import Decimal
pos_inf = Decimal('Infinity')

f1 = 1
f2 = 1
n = 0

while n < pos_inf:
    n = f1 + f2

    f1 = n
    f2 = f1 + f2

    print(f1)
    if(len(str(f1) == 3):
         break
     print(f1 + the number is found)
print(f2)

if(len(str(f2) == 3):
    break
print(f2 + the number is found)
```

This is obviously a Fibonacci generator where at one point one of the number being printed will be 144, and this will be the first number with 3 digits. I am not sure why the above isn't working?

Comment: I adjusted the indentation assuming you had copy/paste difficulty when composing your question.  If your code is *not* indented like above, please fix it and try again to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: "not working" how? Without trying your code, it seems that that `while` loop should run rather a long time.... Should those `if/break` go inside the loop?

Comment: Now I am more confused about what your code actually is.  Please fix the indentation to match what you tried.  Also, add the output you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: Fix the indentation and add quotes to the strings in the `print` statements, then it will work.

Comment: The posted code doesn't run because of mismatched parentheses on the line `if(len(str(f1) == 3):`  Could that be the problem?  Another issue could be indentation.

Comment: You are missing a close paren at the end of your first if statement on line 14.

Comment: `n` will *always* be less than positive infinity. Just use `while True:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have an error in missing parens in your if statements.  This should work:

```
from decimal import Decimal
pos_inf = Decimal('Infinity')
f1 = 1
f2 = 1
n = 0

while n < pos_inf:
    n = f1 + f2

    f1 = n
    f2 = f1 + f2
    print(f1)
    if(len(str(f1)) == 3):
       print(str(f1) + 'the number is found')
       break
    print(f2)
    if(len(str(f2)) == 3):
       print(str(f2) + 'the number is found')
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you calculate Fibonacci number. It should be

```
while n < pos_inf:
    n = f1 + f2
    f2 = f1
    f1 = n
```

Comment: You are adding f2 twice for each iteration

Comment: ahh i see that thanks, but it still produces the correct numbers

Comment: Show me how? What is your `n` after each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Your code had a lot of simple syntax errors(e.g bad parenthesis, bad indentation, and superfluous code) but the concept was mostly right.

The only logical mistake you made was a reduntent use of the `f2` iterator.

Here I fixed your code:

```
from decimal import Decimal
pos_inf = Decimal('Infinity')

f1 = 1
f2 = 1
n = 0

while n < pos_inf:
    n = f1 + f2

    f1 = f2
    f2 = n


    if len(str(f1)) == 3:
       print(str(f1) + " the number is found")
       print(f2)
       break
    print(f1)
```

Which gives us

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144 the number is found
233
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you wanted to indent everything after the while loop

This is what you want to do:

```
f1 = f2
f2 = n
```

Also, once f1 hits a 3 digit number, you're code will print it, then break.

Also, you need quotes in your print statement and turn your integers into strings:

```
print(str(f1) + ' the number is found')
```

Comment: I am changing both f1 and f2 in the same iteration... rather than change f1 at a time

Answer (score 0):

if you just looking for first 3 digit febbonaci number, then below code should work

```
from decimal import Decimal
pos_inf = Decimal('Infinity')

f1 = 1
f2 = 1
n = 0

while n < pos_inf :
    n = f1 + f2
    f1 = f2
    f2 = n
    print(f2)
    if (len(str(f2)) == 3):
        break

print f2, "3 digit number found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this. Although I couldn't get past an error pertaining to the pos_inf variable you're using. It said it couldn't convert infinity to an integer. Maybe that's causing an issue for you.

```
var1 = var2 = 1
result = 0

print(result)
print(var1)
print(var2)

for x in range(1,100):
    result = var1 + var2
    print(result)
    var2 = var1
    var1 = result
    if result == 144:
        print("The number has been found")
        break
```